# How to re-use Appium driver

Tags: appium

Wondering if I can set `newCommandTimeout` to a higher number, and have test just re-use current drivers. Is this possible?

The driver variable will got out of scope when the test ends, but the I should be able to re-initialize a new driver variable with the current session.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `newCommandTimeout` to any value, but I doubt there is a need to increase it above 60-90.

I'm creating AppiumDriver instance once per suite run, so all tests use the same driver; I added driver session status check before each tests, and in case smth went wrong - create driver session.

But it does not require any manipulation with `newCommandTimeout` capability. Just design your tests the way they can have access to global driver instance, or create multiple for simulation run.
I'm not sure you can re-initiate driver object and link it to existing session, but thats for sure is not a reliable approach with Appium - session might die for multiple unexpected reasons, so would have to create new session.

Comment: `I'm not sure you can re-initiate driver object and link it to existing session, but thats for sure is not a reliable approach with Appium` it's just that when I am developing a test, I have to reinitialize the driver every time, and the reinitialization just takes too long, creating tests is a really slow process

Comment: Slowness is the reason I'm using one instance of driver for suite, e.g. 17 android tests. Whats the problem to create driver in `beforeSuite`, check health in `beforeTest` and use it in every test? Been doing it in both java and js, not a big deal implement in whatever language you are using

Comment: I have to re-run my tests multiple times while I'm developing them, and it just becomes tedious to wait for the driver to initialize. I have hundreds of tests to write, and I need a quick way of writing and tweaking them.

Comment: if you plan to write hundreds of ui tests (that sounds really strange strategy, https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestPyramid.html) then appium is not tool that makes your life easier: driver never goes fast like native framework and single instance can't be used for hours - I can see sometimes it hangs. As I said - create it once and use globally, if you want snippet - just ask for it. Btw espresso for Android/xcuitest for iOS would be a more suitable option in a world of "hundreds" ui tests, but its not a black-box testing but maybe its not your goal.

Comment: It doesn't matter if the driver hangs up, it can be programmed to start back up; btw your solution doesn't prevent hangup. Why is it a strange strategy? I want to cache the driver and reuse it. Doesn't sounds strange at all to me. In fact I was thinking of just running the driver on a tcp server.